# A question about left invariant vector fields

Tags: lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

Let $G$ be a Lie group with bi-invariant metric $\langle , \rangle$ and $X,Y,Z$ left invariant vector fields in $G$, how to conclude that $X\langle Y,Z\rangle=0$?

Comment: What have you tried until now? Where are you stuck? Why do not you take a look at Manfredo Perdigao do Carmo 'Riemannian Geometry'? There is a traitment of this point in §2.6 on Lie Groups on pages 40-41. Cf. for example here: http://books.google.it/books?id=ct91XCWkWEUC&pg=PA40&lpg=PA40&dq=bi-invariant+metric+and+left+invariant+vector+fields&source=bl&ots=ewy957RfTH&sig=a05P2qVBTvcfze9n-c37Rne4YHA&hl=it&sa=X&ei=a2rKT42yM4jf4QTKvrQQ&ved=0CIQBEOgBMAk#v=onepage&q=bi-invariant%20metric%20and%20left%20invariant%20vector%20fields&f=false

Comment: I don't know where to use the condition "left invariant". I read that chapter, but I still don't know the answer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function
$$
G \ni g \mapsto \langle Y_g, Z_g \rangle
$$
is constant since
$$
\langle Y_g, Z_g\rangle = \langle dL_g Y_e, dL_g Z_e\rangle = \langle Y_e, Z_e\rangle.
$$
So differentiating it by $X$ gives 0.  Note we have used the facts that $Y$ and $Z$ are left-invariant but $X$ need not be.

Comment: Why is $\langle dL_g Y_e, dL_g Z_e\rangle = \langle Y_e, Z_e\rangle$?

Comment: That's what it means for the metric to be biinvariant.